# How is it possible to unite multiple types in the operator function called by std::visit in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std-variant

I am using std::variant and std::visit to call operator functions. I have a lot of variants (which mostly inherit from one superclass), but most of the operator functions should return the same value. Is there a way to have one operator function, which is called everytime one of those child-classes is called (such as if a normal function is called with a child-class as a parameter and if there is no such function, the (overlaoded) function is called, if the super-class is a parameter.

This may be easier to understand with an example:

I have two superclasses:
`struct function_node; struct nary_node;`
I also have multiple classes which inherit from those superclasses:

```
struct addition_node : function_node, nary_node;
struct division_node: function_node, nary_node;
struct cos_node: function_node, nary_node;
```

I have another class which has those classes as variants:

```
struct value_node{
   var get_variant(){
      return std::variant<
                 addition_node*,
                 division_node*,
                 cos_node*
              >;
   }
};
```

I finally have a last class (constant_checker), which evaluates the expressions.

```
double eval(value_node* node){
   return std::visit(*this, node->get_variant());
}
```

In this last class I am currently having multiple operator functions of the form:

```
double operator(division_node* node){
   return 0; 
}
```

This works fine, but I actually have multiple dozen of those children-nodes. Since the operator function should all return the same value, I want a single operator function for this, e.g.

```
double operator(function_node* node){
   return 0;
}
```

I have tried it in this exact way, but I receive the error

```
3>C:\...\include\variant(1644): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::_C_invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
3>C:\...\include\variant(1644): note: With the following template arguments:
3>C:\...\include\variant(1644): note: '_Callable=ale::util::constant_checker &'
3>C:\...\include\variant(1644): note: '_Types={ale::minus_node *}'
3>C:\...\include\variant(1656): error C2955: 'std::_All_same': use of class template requires template argument list
```

This error will go away, if I insert the operator function for this exact node (minus_node in this case) and then occurr again for the other nodes, so appearently the general oeprator function is not called.

Is there any solution to this or do I have to keep every operator function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use template `operator()`:

```
template<class Node>
double operator()(Node* node) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Node, addition_node>) {
    // ...
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Node, division_node>) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your visitor should be in a way that all:

- `visitor(variant1);`
- `visitor(variant2);`
- ..
- `visitor(variantN);`

are valid.

So yes you can group some.

Here

```
double operator(function_node* node){ return 0; }
```

would suffice.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcb461d9d324e16b).

Comment: But unfortunaly I still get the error, even though I think all visitors should be valid. The example I gave might be a little narrow, in reality there are hundreds of nested classes. For example the minus node struct minus_node : derived_value_node<minus_node, real<0>>, unary_node<real<0>> {using kary_node::kary_node;};
is giving me an error, even though operators for derived_value_node and kary_node exist (I tried unary_node as well).

Comment: @wittn: next time, create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As is the question is answered. You should probably ask another question. (Modifying question in a way which breaks existing answer is bad).